# Open file with input name

Tags: c++, string, file-io, stringstream

I've got this piece of code in C++ from someone else that I am now working with but I'm not sure why the "std::string()" is been added.

```
std::ifstream File;
std::stringstream FileName;
FileName << Name; //Name being a string that has been passed as an input to the function.
                 // Eg."MyFile"
newFileName << ".txt"; //"MyFile.txt"

File.open(std::string(FileName.str()).c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

My question is, since str() returns a string, and c_str() gets a string and transforms it into c string, why do we need to put it inside the "string()"? Could it not be writen like:

```
File.open((FileName.str()).c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

Comment: std::string() create another temp string object, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be written like this.

Using

```
std::string(FileName.str())
```

is absolutely meaningless.

Comment: So what I wrote is fine eventhough I don't have "using namespace std;" included in my file, right? Thanks for your quick answer!!

Comment: @Mulan - yes, it's fine, because toy don't need to have access to this name in this case, using just `.str()` is OK.